# Passing a local array that declared in a function to another one

Tags: c, arrays

My title clearly expresses my question. let me take an opportunity :
Look at the following code please :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int myf2(int *ser){
    *ser=4;
    printf("\nsecond=%d",*ser);
    return 0;   
}
int myf1(){
    int fil[2];
    fil[0]=1;
    printf("\nfirst=%d",*fil);
    myf2(fil);
    printf("\nthird=%d",*fil);
    return 0;
}
int main(){
    myf1();
}
```

I expected this output :

```
first=1
second=4
third=1
```

While the output is :

```
first=1
second=4
third=4
```

So how do i can pass *fil* array to *myf2* function so that third printf prints 1 rather than 4

And could you explain why my code is wrong !? I declare this array locally. but as you see it's not local in truth :)

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable is in fact two things, an *identifier*, the name that you give it and an *object*, the thing that you name.

The concept of scope only applies to the identifier: it is the part of the code in which the object is accessible under the name that you have given it. Scope is a compile time feature.

Objects don't have scope, they have a lifetime. In the case of a local variable as you have it here, the lifetime starts when your execution enters the scope where the variable is declared and ends when you leave it for good. During the call to `myf2` your object continues to exist, and can thus be accessed without problems.

This access is done through the pointer that you have passed to the function in the call. Since the pointer points to the original object, all changes that you do here are changes to the original object, and are still visible when you return from the call.

Comment: Thanks. @Jens. But i didn't follow. could you explain object part more clear !?
And look at this code please : https://ideone.com/IjXl4a
Here, I just write a variable rather than an array. and the scope applied successfully. why !?

Comment: @AlirezaHosseini, I think you'd have to learn the concept of pointers. A pointer "points" to an object, this is what your original function receives. Your other functions receives an `int` and not an `int*`. So here the value is copied into a new variable.

Comment: That's it :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an array to a function, you're really passing a pointer to the first element in the list.

In your function, `ser` points to index 0 in the list.  So `*ser` is the same as `ser[0]`.  Likewise, where `fil` is defined, `*fil` is equivalent to `fil[0]`.

Comment: Thanks @dbush. But as you see. this array is local. So it shouldn't change. As we see in local variables that they don't change in parent function (by other functions modifications.)

Answer (score 1):

Of-course pass the array by value. Unfortunately that is impossible in current 'C' language (because bad design decisions). That's why you should use a structure hack, making you array instead a data member because structures can be copied directly. So your example will looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
     int d[2];
} array_of_2;

int myf2(array_of_2 ser){
    *ser.d=4;
    printf("\nsecond=%d",*ser.d);
    return 0;   
}
int myf1(){
    array_of_2 fil;
    fil.d[0]=1;
    printf("\nfirst=%d",*fil.d);
    myf2(fil);
    printf("\nthird=%d",*fil.d);
    return 0;
}
int main(){
    myf1();
}
```

You'll have to refer to the array using dot and 'd' unfortunately because the type 'array_of_2' is actually a structure.

What happens in your case is that you're actually passing a pointer to your array first element. So 'myf2' local (which is also a function parameter) 'ser' will only receive the address of the local in the scope of 'myf1' and then edit it.

Some illustrations:

[image]

[image]

Local variables and all other types of such (as global ones) are special only with their life-time. Otherwise there is no restriction as from which function you can edit them.

A variable is reserved memory when first it's declaration is met and freed when it's scope ends (in the case of locals when the function returns). Meanwhile this memory can be freely edited by other functions.

Comment: Thanks but I think you didn't understand my question correctly! I want to do this by array. Nor struct. You mean it's impossible !? :o

Comment: Yeah it's - 'C' language won't allow you to pass arrays by value. It's a bad design decision and it was taken because back in the time it was costly and a common practice was instead to pass the array pointer instead of it's data. That's why the array-to-pointer implicit conversion was created. Besides the hack with the structure isn't beautiful, it does exactly what do you want.

Comment: That's why you would often need to write 'for' loops to copy arrays. Or you could apply the structure hack.

Comment: You should need to know that arrays have their own type which is different then a pointer. For more information you can search the internet for ['array to pointer decay'](https://www.google.bg/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=array%20to%20pointer%20decay).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your code. The local array remains until the `myf1`'s scope is there. Its just that you pass address of base element of array to function thus making change to original array.

So to solve your problem-

1. `int myf2(int *ser)`  declare you function as `int myf2(int ser)`
2. In function do `ser=4`.
3. In function `myf1` call `myf2` like this -`myf2(*fil);`

So value of `fil` won't change because the copy of `*fil` is created and  modified to `4` and thus keeping original value of `*fil`  intact.

Working code-https://ideone.com/g32wnQ

Comment: Yes. Could you explain me why in this mode the value doesn't change. But in my code it changes !?

Comment: @AlirezaHosseini  In solution value doesn't change as we pass array's value not address. Thus copy of that is created and changes are made to that keeping orginal value intact.

Comment: Thanks. Thus in my attempted code, I pass the exact address of index. so changes are applied to memory location of array index.. Is it true !?

Comment: @AlirezaHosseini  Yes , in your method the value at the address is modified ,thus value of original array is modified. How this is modified , is that `ser` get changed and `ser` points to address of `fil` and subsequently `fil` gets changed.

Comment: So can we say "The array scope in this way wasn't important. because we are change the exact memory value." ?

Comment: @AlirezaHosseini  Array scope  was not important in these both functions as you pass address and mainly  because `myf2` was called inside `myf1` where array was live as scope of `myf1` was not terminated.Else it would be problem.

Comment: @AlirezaHosseini   I don't  follow ?

Comment: I mean this comment
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255218/passing-a-local-array-that-declared-in-a-function-to-another-one/32255316?noredirect=1#comment52391297_32255316
when i change code as this
`#include <stdio.h>
int myf2(int ser){
 ser=4;
 printf("\nsecond=%d",ser);
 return 0; 
}
int myf1(){
 int fil=1;
 printf("\nfirst=%d",fil);
 myf2(fil);
 printf("\nthird=%d",fil);
 return 0;
}
int main(){
 myf1();
}`
Your comment will wrong..

Comment: @AlirezaHosseini  Ohh I got it . I  confused you about the address part ._Yes I was wrong about the address part made a blunder_ . **Let me frame it again - _mainly because myf2 was called inside myf1 where array was live as scope of myf1 was not terminated_ **.The part about address would lead to **UB** ,so avoid that _my bad_.